# Implementing instant search with firebase and algolia

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

So I've implemented search functionality into a site using firebase and algolia. But it's underperforming: it takes too long (over 5s) to get back results and I think that's due to its structure. This is how it works:

1. A change in the firebase database triggers a query using cloud functions.
2. Algolia does it magic and returns an array of hits.
3. That result is stored in the firebase database.
4. The client renders the results stored in the firebase database.

It's messy and I don't wanna have to store search results in the database. What am I missing here? I also would like to avoid the use of instantsearch.js

Any ideas? Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Algolia is designed to be used directly from your front-end, just like the Firebase SDK. See their [JS API](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/getting-started/) for more info.

I think what you want to do is use Cloud Functions to populate data from your Realtime Database to Algolia, but then query Algolia directly from the browser instead of the multiple layers of indirection you have currently.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.